# Client Browser to change Server side file system/change the source code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way that an action initiated by a user, on a client Browser( like clicking a button), can change characteristics of the page loaded by other clients.

The reason I need this is for controlling a device that post information onto a page and waits for a response to see if it can still continue posting information or not. I want that response to come from the user viewing the page. Both client browsers load the page from the server and they are not related in any way.

Thanks

Comment: Like a chat system? One client sends information to the server, and it sends it to the other client.

Comment: You might need to push data from the server to the other clients. Look into comet or web sockets.

Comment: @Barmar The chat analogy does satisfy the basic operation that I need to done. How do chat site work? or should I ask Google.

Comment: @carvelle: This question has quiet broad scope.. try searching on google .. you can use 1- AJAX long polling to check if some changes have been performed, 2- web sockets like blessenm pointed out, 3- node.js which is the most widely used solution nowadays for these type of stuff .. etc(there maybe more methods)